# Laravel: Form to update multiple rows in table?

Tags: php, mysql, forms, laravel, laravel-4

I understand that I can create a binding on my form to be able to access and update a record on the table like below:

```
@extends('layouts.interior')

@section('content')

{{ Form::model($nav) }}
<ul id="sortable">
    <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>
        {{ Form::text('url') }}
    </li>
    <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>
        {{ Form::text('url_name') }}
    </li>       
</ul>           
{{ Form::close() }}

@stop
```

But this is done by passing a single id from the route

```
Route::get('nav/edit/{id}')
```

So this only is useful if I only need to display and update one record/row to the user. Basically like a blog entry that has a title, body for that one row. I just want to user to go to the route /nav/edit/ and it displays all of the rows for the nav as an editable input to be sent back to the database.

**My question is**, how can I retrieve multiple rows from the table and display their values into input fields that can be tracked and posted for each of their ids when a user edits their fields?

Example:

I have a table as follows:

id | url | url_name |

I want to retrieve each url and populate a form with an input for each so the user can update the url and it's display name and then send it back to the database to update it's new value.

Something like this below would generate an input field for each, but there is nothing to tell Laravel on submit where the values should go and what they should be replacing.

```
@foreach($links as $link)
<li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>
    {{ Form::text($link->url_name, $link->url_name, array('id' => $link->id, 'name' => $link->url_name)) }}
</li>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use link id as array key in input name so you can know which value belongs to which id

```
<input type='text' value="{{ $link->url_name }}" name="url_name[{{ $link->id }}]">
```

it will send array like:

```
$_POST[
    'url_name'=>array(
         '3'=>'url_name1',
         '5'=>'url_name2',
         '7'=> 'url_name3'
    )
 ]
```